# Find out foreign key reference table

Tags: table, sybase

How to find out all the foreign key reference tables for a table in Sybase by writing a Query .

Answer (score 1):

The system provided `sp_helpconstraint` should do the trick.

If you want to write your own code then I'd suggest you take a look at the source code for `sp_helpconstraint`, see where/how it derives the constraint data, then write your own query(s) to generate the desired result set.

To find the source code for `sp_helpconstraint` you can either look in the `installmaster` script, or run `exec sybsystemprocs..sp_helptext sp_helpconstraint,null,null,showsql`.